# Adding Cache headers via a Web.config for specific locations only

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, cache-control

We have an application that has been developed by the third party, and I don't want to go back to them to get them to add in cache control for specific pages.

All the pages that need caching disabled are in a single directory.

The issue is that IE seems to not follow Cache-control:nocache properly, so we need to add in Pragma:nocache and cache age as well.

Is there a way to do this using configs in the directory? will it cascade through all child directories?  Can it be done via the main web.config?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a way to do this via code, it needs to be via configuration of either IIS or the web.config files.

We're using ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0, on IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in IIS using the UI, it's actually quite easy, or atleast it was in my use case.

All you do is simply open up IIS manager, navigate to the site and then the directory you want to add the headers to Right Click -> properties.

Click the "Headers" tab, and add in the headers you require.

This goes recursively down the child directories, and adds the headers before any added by the code.

In IIS 7.0/7.5, you can use the StaticContent section of a web.config in each of the directories.

Comment: Get +1.5 to find it from me :)

Comment: Can it be done for some specific URL, my application is an MVC3 application.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but the `<location>` sections of the web.config may have this ability?  I'll report back if I come across anything though

Answer (score 1):

You can do that on global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if (cTheFile.Contains("/ExtraDir/"))
    {
        // add your header here
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");    
    }

    //... rest code of...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for a why to do this via configuration rather than code based.  I'll update the question

Comment: additional headers can be loaded by the IIS metabase, which means it can be done.  It can also be done via the static content element in IIS7.0.

Comment: You can add it on a Directory basis, which is what the question is.  They are all in a Single directory.  You can add headers to everything from a directory it seems.

Comment: See my answer, it's possible even if they're not setup as Virtual Directories.